# Very slow performance processing 40M+ records MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, database, performance

I am processing over 40M records on a MySQL database. The scenario is as follows:

Given 2 tables with same structure containing over 40M price info records:

**Table 1**

```
product_id  price    date
101         5.7      2016/1/1
102         11.6     2016/1/1
104         8        2016/1/1
…           …         …
```

**Table 2**

```
product_id  price    date
101         5.9      2016/1/2
103         20.3     2016/1/2
104         8        2016/1/2
…           …         …
```

I'm looking to find out how many product_id's exist on both tables and I'm using the below queries to search:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM t1 a,t2 b where a.product_id=b.product_id ;

SELECT count(*) FROM t1 a,t2 b on a.product_id=b.product_id ;
```

It takes over half an hour to get the results, is there any way to improve the performance?

Comment: Look up explain and the use of indexes

Comment: Question lacks table structure, storage engine in question, output of `EXPLAIN` and hardware being used. Performance depends on many factors, not just your query and amount of records. Hardware plays a HUGE role.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to create an index on `product_id`.

To do this read [create index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html) i.e.

```
create index idx_1 on t1 (product_id);
create index idx_2 on t2 (product_id);
```